# AjaxControlToolkit runtime error in MonoDevelop

Tags: ajax, mono, ajaxcontroltoolkit, monodevelop

My project builds just fine but upon runtime I get this:

System.Web.HttpException: Code generation failed. ---> System.Web.HttpException: Code generation failed. ---> System.TypeLoadException: Could not load type 'System.Web.Script.AjaxFrameworkAssemblyAttribute' from assembly 'AjaxControlToolkit'.

Is Ajax not fully supported? I'm running MonoDevelop (2.6) and mono (2.10.5) on Mac OS X Lion.

Comment: It is not Mono's responsiblity to support a library like AJAX Control Toolkit. The developers of the toolkit should test their bits on Mono and ensure interoperability. Please try to report this issue to their web site and see how they reply, http://ajaxcontroltoolkit.codeplex.com/